# Images on website get cropped off on mobile (Shopify)

Tags: css, shopify

I'm having some trouble setting up my Shopify page. It seems like it's working as intended, but I want it to work differently.

On mobile the pictures from the slideshow get cropped off - instead I want it to keep the aspect ratio and just get scaled down. The page is [www.dasnoteboard.net](http://www.dasnoteboard.net)

I'm thankful for any suggestions because I'm really a n00b when it comes to webdesign :(.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to post your code?

Comment: It's gonna be related to either or both the CSS for the images and the HTML markup for them. But there's not going to be a non-code solution.